# Better way of doing isset($variable) and check variable value

Tags: php

I was wondering if there's a better way than what I always do to check the value of a variable that might not be set? For example :

```
if(isset($_SESSION['super_user']) && $_SESSION['super_user'] == true) {
  echo 'hi super user';
}
```

It would much simpler to just do this :

```
if($_SESSION['super_user']) {
  echo 'hi super user';
}
```

But I would end up with a notice of undefined index. Is there another way of doing such kind of simple validation or I must stick with my actual way of doing it?

Thanks

Comment: Is `$_SESSION['super_user']` ever false, or is it only set when true?

Comment: Only set when true ... this is not my code, I'm just maintaining an application, but like some answered below, variables should always be defined in the first place, and have a default value. But in this case, it's only set when it's a SU

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['super_user'])) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could initially set `$_SESSION['super_user']` to `false` and only set it to `true` if the user is a *super user*. Then you can always use `if ($_SESSION['super_user']) {}`.

Answer (score 0):

For the particular example your current code could be shortened to

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['super_user']))
```

however, the right way would be

```
if ($_SESSION['role'] == 'super_user')
```

> I was wondering if there's a better way than what I always do to check the value of a variable that might not be set?

Yes. Always define all your variables. Like one I posted above. Always have a `role` element for all your users and there will be no need to check if it ever exists.